# xslt copy-of to different namespace in the resulting document

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In my xslt code, I can use copy-of to copy the element and its descendant nodes, but the catch is that the resulting schema though has the same structure has a different namespace. Is there any way I can still use copy-of and accomplish this? I am using XSLT 2.0

Following is the example of Source and Target XMLs, the cd elements can be copied using copy-of in XSL, but they have different namespaces.

Source XML

```
<catalog xmlns="namespace1">
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Target XML

```
<books xmlns="namespace2">
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</books>
```

Used Martin Honnen's idea and created this

```
<xsl:template name="changeNamespace">
<xsl:param name="nodes"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count(child::*)>0">
      <xsl:element name="newnamespace:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:call-template name="changeNamespace">
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="./child::*"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="newnamespace:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the problem properly with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `xsl:copy` or `xsl:copy-of` to change the namespace of a node, you need to transform the nodes with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:*">
  <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

which then assumes you have e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="source-namespace" xmlns:ns2="target-namespace" version="1.0">` in scope or you can of course also put the target namespace into the `xsl:element`:

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:*">
  <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}" namespace="target-namespace">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If you have attributes where you need to change the namespace you need to set up a similar template for attribute nodes.

With XSLT 2.0 you can simplify the stylesheet structure with e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="namespace1" xmlns="namespace2" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Is there any way I can run this template (to change namespace) after the xsl:copy-of is executed? I can execute the first XSL which has xsl:copy-of and then use the result to run through another XSL which has template to change the namespaces, but is there any way I can combine these 2 in one XSL?

Comment: I am not sure why you would first want to copy something to transform in a second step but of course it is possible in XSLT 2, for a clean solution I would suggest to use modes to separate the processing steps, i.e. set up my suggestion for a certain mode with the use of `<xsl:template match="*" mode="change-ns"><xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="namespace2"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/></xsl:element></xsl:template>` and push your copy through that mode using `<xsl:apply-templates select="$variable" mode="change-ns"/>`.